# Difference between <> and != comparison operators?

Tags: java, sqlite, comparison, operators

What is the difference between <> and != operators. Both operators perform same action.

**When to use <> ? and
When to use != ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've added the `sqlite` tag: They [mean the same thing](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> Note that there are two variations of the equals and not equals operators. Equals can be either `=` or `==`. The non-equals operator can be either `!=` or `<>`.

And in fact, that seems to be a common theme across languages: In languages that allow both, they mean the same thing. (Various references below.)

Some languages only allow one or the other. In Java, you use `!=` for "not equals;" you can't use `<>` (it means something else and is used in a different context). In VB.Net, it's the other way around: `<>` is valid, and `!=` is not.

But a lot of languages allow both:

- [T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) and [MySQL's variant of SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) (and Oracle seems to [have both and a couple more](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/operator.htm#997833)). In all three cases, they're different ways of writing the same thing. The Wikipedia page on SQL [says `<>` is standard, but most rDBMS's also allow `!=`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators).
- PHP [supports both](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and again they mean the same thing.
- [So does Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) (again they're the same thing).

Answer (score 3):

`<>` is not used for comparison in Java. `!=` is.

`<>` (diamond operator) is used since Java 7 in generic type initialization. For example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>;
```